# Инициализация DateTime

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Как правильно инициализировать `DateTime ^date1 = new DateTime(2008, 5, 1, 8, 30, 52)`, чтобы использовать его структуре `FileInfo`:

```
FileInfo ^ info = gcnew FileInfo(name);
info->CreationTime = dateTimePicker1->Value;
info->LastAccessTime = dateTimePicker1->Value;
info->LastWriteTime = dateTimePicker1->Value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` - это структура, значимый тип, в терминологии .NET. Поэтому создавать его следует на стеке.

Возможны два варианта синтаксиса:

```
// 1
DateTime date1(2008, 5, 1, 8, 30, 52);
// 2
DateTime date1 = DateTime(2008, 5, 1, 8, 30, 52);
```

Далее используем его так:

```
info->CreationTime = date1;
```

---

При желании можно создать структуру не на стеке, а в куче:

```
DateTime ^date1 = gcnew DateTime(2008, 5, 1, 8, 30, 52);
```

Тут используется *управляемый* указатель `^` и оператор `gcnew`.
Далее, для присвоения, нужно его разыменовать. Делается это оператором `*`. Как ни странно, применяется *звёздочка* (как и в случае с нативными указателями), а не *крышка*.

```
info->CreationTime = *date1;
```

Вероятно, лучше всего первый, самый лаконичный, вариант.

Comment: Вы просто невероятный!!! СПАСИБО!!!!!!!!